# Async/Await with Request-Promise returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, cheerio

I have two files; server.js and scrape.js, below are the code snippets as they currently stand.

server.js:

```
const scrape = require("./scrape");

async function start() {
    const response = await scrape.start();
    console.log(response);
}

start();
```

and scrape.js:

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const request = require("request-promise");

go = async () => {

const options = {
  uri: "http://www.somewebsite.com/something",
  transform: function(body) {
    return cheerio.load(body);
  }
};

request(options)
  .then($ => {
    let scrapeTitleArray = [];
    $(".some-class-in-html").each(function(i, obj) {
      const data = $(this)
        .text()
        .trim();
      scrapeTitleArray.push(data);
    });
    return scrapeTitleArray;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};

module.exports = {
  start: go
};
```

So when I spin up server.js, I return undefined to the console.log(response), when I actually want to return the array i've been pushing to, can you see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't "go" return a promise?

Comment: @McMurphy If i'm not mistaken, declaring it as an async function automatically returns a promise?

Comment: `.each()` uses a "callback". You need to wrap that in a promise and resolve it's result. Otherwise the code just skips straight to returning the empty array. You need to `return` the `request` result of course, but if you don't respect the callback then you're still going to have problems.

Comment: `go` is an [implicitly global variable](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Don't do that.

Comment: Why do you define `go` as an `async` function but then nowhere use `await`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to `return` something from your `async` function (a return inside a then does not return from the main function). Either a promise or something you `await`-ed.

Also, make sure to declare your `go` variable to avoid leaking it into the global space.

```
const go = async () => {

  const options = {
    uri: "http://www.somewebsite.com/something",
    transform: function(body) {
      return cheerio.load(body);
    }
  };

  return request(options)
    .then($ => {
      let scrapeTitleArray = [];
      $(".some-class-in-html").each(function(i, obj) {
        const data = $(this)
          .text()
          .trim();
        scrapeTitleArray.push(data);
      });
      return scrapeTitleArray;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Since you are using an `async` function, you might want to take advantage of the `await` syntax also.

```
const go = async () => {

  const options = {
    uri: "http://www.somewebsite.com/something",
    transform: function(body) {
      return cheerio.load(body);
    }
  };

  try {
    const $ = await request(options);
    $(".some-class-in-html").each(function(i, obj) {
      const data = $(this)
        .text()
        .trim();
      scrapeTitleArray.push(data);
    });
    return scrapeTitleArray;
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: `.each()` has a callback does it not?

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes `.each` uses a synchronous callback (so it's ok to use here).

Comment: [So it is](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/blob/master/lib/api/traversing.js#L298-L302)

Comment: @NeilLunn (of course `map` should be preferred over `each`+`push`)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your `go` function isn't returning any value.

You're calling `request(options).then(...)`, but what follows from that promise is never returned by `go`. I recommend you add a `return` statement:

```
go = async () => {

  const options = {
    uri: "http://www.somewebsite.com/something",
    transform: function(body) {
      return cheerio.load(body);
    }
  };

  // The only difference is that it says "return" here:
  return request(options)
    .then($ => {
      let scrapeTitleArray = [];
      $(".some-class-in-html").each(function(i, obj) {
        const data = $(this)
          .text()
          .trim();
        scrapeTitleArray.push(data);
      });
      return scrapeTitleArray;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```