# How to return data from loop in order in node

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, cheerio

I am creating a web scraper that scrapes all of the movies coming out for the next year from this site (https://www.imdb.com/movies-coming-soon/) and it loops through an array of links that contain all the movies for each month for the next year, its working but the only problem is that its not returning them in order due to node.js asynchronous behavior, how do i get it to loop through the array and return the data in order?

Ive tried to make a callback function but I don't know where it would go at

```
const request = require('request')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')

const movieArray = [ '/movies-coming-soon/2019-09/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2019-10/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2019-11/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2019-12/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-01/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-02/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-03/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-04/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-05/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-06/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-07/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-08/' ]
for (let i = 0; i < movieArray.length; i++) {
    request.get('https://www.imdb.com' + movieArray[i] , (err, res, body) => {
        if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(res.request.href)
            const $ = cheerio.load(body)
            //console.log(next)
            $('h4').each((i, v) => {
                const date = $(v).text()
                console.log(date)
            })               
        }
    })
}
```

I'm expecting it to return the data in order instead of it being returned in a order based off how fast the data is returned due to nodes asynchronous behavior

Comment: What result are you trying to collect in order?  Every date?

Comment: @jfriend00 the dates and the movies that release on that date, it returns them, but in the wrong order when it loops through the array of links

Comment: Where the movie in the results you show?  I only see you getting the date.

Comment: @jfriend00 the date const contains both the date and the movie,

Answer (score 1):

It's a classic async issue in for loop as per explained https://lavrton.com/javascript-loops-how-to-handle-async-await-6252dd3c795/. Below would be the solution:

```
// const request = require('request')
const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const movieArray = [
  '/movies-coming-soon/2019-09/',
  '/movies-coming-soon/2019-10/',
  '/movies-coming-soon/2019-11/',
  '/movies-coming-soon/2019-12/',
  '/movies-coming-soon/2020-01/',
  '/movies-coming-soon/2020-02/',
  '/movies-coming-soon/2020-03/',
  '/movies-coming-soon/2020-04/',
  '/movies-coming-soon/2020-05/',
  '/movies-coming-soon/2020-06/',
  '/movies-coming-soon/2020-07/',
  '/movies-coming-soon/2020-08/',
];

async function processMovieArray(array) {
  for (const item of array) {
    await getMovie(item);
  }
  console.log('Done');
}

async function getMovie(item) {
  const options = {
    method: `GET`,
    uri: 'https://www.imdb.com' + item,
  };
  const response = await request(options);
  const $ = cheerio.load(response.body);
  $('h4').each((i, v) => {
    const date = $(v).text();
    console.log(date);
  });
}

processMovieArray(movieArray);
```

Comment: Im getting an error on saying ``` const $ = await cheerio.load(body)
                      ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function```

Comment: My bad as cheerio.load() is synchronous... And request is not asynchronous as well. Code is updated or you can follow @jfriend00 's solution

Comment: i thought the regular request library is async, how would u go about doing it in that library, not the request-promise one, cause im not really that familiar with promises

Comment: here is a related discussion with similar use case about promise and where you may find their code useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47341603/async-await-with-request-promise-returns-undefined

Answer (score 0):

The low tech way that deviates the least from your current code is to just use the index of your `for` loop to populate an array.  Since `let` in the `for` loop will make a separate variable for `i` for each iteration of the `for` loop, we can use that index inside the async callback to reference the desired spot in a results array.  Then, you also use a `cntr` to know when you've finished with all the results:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

if (!Array.prototype.flat) {
    Array.prototype.flat = function() {
        return this.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);
    }
}


const movieArray = [ '/movies-coming-soon/2019-09/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2019-10/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2019-11/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2019-12/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-01/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-02/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-03/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-04/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-05/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-06/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-07/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-08/' ];

let results = [];
let cntr = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < movieArray.length; i++) {
    request.get('https://www.imdb.com' + movieArray[i] , (err, res, body) => {
        ++cntr;
        if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(res.request.href)
            const $ = cheerio.load(body)
            //console.log(next)
            let textArray = [];
            $('h4').each((i, v) => {
                console.log(date)
                textArray.push($(v).text());
            });
            results[i] = textArray;
        }
        if (cntr === moveArray.length) {
            // all results are done now
            let allResults = results.flat();
        }
    })
}
```

A bit more elegant way is to switch over to promises and let the promise infrastructure keep everything in order for you:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

if (!Array.prototype.flat) {
    Array.prototype.flat = function() {
        return this.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);
    }
}

const movieArray = [ '/movies-coming-soon/2019-09/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2019-10/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2019-11/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2019-12/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-01/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-02/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-03/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-04/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-05/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-06/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-07/',
'/movies-coming-soon/2020-08/' ];

// 
if (!Array.prototype.flat) {
    Array.prototype.flat = function() {
        return this.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);
    }
}

Promise.all(movieArray.map(path => {
    return rp('https://www.imdb.com' + path).then(body => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(body);
        let textArray = [];
        $('h4').each((i, v) => {
            // console.log($(v).text());
            textArray.push($(v).text());
        });
        return textArray;

    }).catch(err => {
        // ignore errors on urls that didn't work
        // so we can get the rest of the results without aborting
        console.log("err");
        return undefined;
    });
})).then(results => {
    // flatten the two level array and remove empty items
    let allResults = results.flat().filter(item => !!item);
    console.log(allResults);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

FYI, I tested the 2nd version in nodejs version 10.16.0 and it works.

Comment: @kendallkelly - Did this work for you?  Did you get a chance to try it?